# Wordpress site goes black and white occasionally

Tags: wordpress, themes, refresh

[wordpress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2uaG.png)

The page works fine in normal times but I got half black and half white screen while loading the website. This is very unpredictable about when and how the issue occurs. I already tried to solve by removing all plugins but it didn't work as expected. I also tried changing the .htaccess file but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your theme , may be your any theme file has broken !!

Comment: thanks for your help after i changed my theme the problem has not arrived